# Replace every Number in String with a String in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I think my desire is quite forward.

So I have a string e.g. "abc1abc2abc3"
I want to replace every number with the Char 'X' time the given Number.
So "abc1abc2abc3" -> "abcXabcXXabcXXX"

I know i only get Integers `<9` so I thought doing something like:

```
myFunction givenString = let
    replaceEveryNumber '1' = 'X'
    replaceEveryNumber '8' = "XXXXXXXX"
    replaceEveryNumber c = c
    in map replaceEveryNumber myFunction
```

And yeah this does not really work because of different types.

I could also apply a similiar function to a [String] for my desire. So I could change from the code above '1' = 'X' to "1" = "X" and so on, but the problem here is that if I have ["abc2abc", "8"] the result is ["abc2abc", "XXXXXXXX"] so it ignores the char in the String in !!0, which I guess makes sense but I still don't know how to do it correctly.

I hope someone can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems here. You are not mapping over `givenString`, but over `myFunction`. Since `myFunction` is a function, that will not work. We thus should replace the mapping expression with:

```
myFunction givenString = let … in map replaceEveryNumber givenString
```

Furthermore the `replaceEveryNumber` can only return values of one type, your function however returns a `Char`, and the other lines return a `String`. Since your function should be able to return a sequence of multiple `Char`s, we thus should return a string for every line. For `c` we will need to wrap it in a singleton list to convert the `Char` to a `String` with that character:

```
myFunction givenString = let
    replaceEveryNumber '1' = "X"
    replaceEveryNumber '2' = "XX"
    replaceEveryNumber '3' = "XXX"
    replaceEveryNumber '4' = "XXXX"
    replaceEveryNumber '5' = "XXXXX"
    replaceEveryNumber '6' = "XXXXXX"
    replaceEveryNumber '7' = "XXXXXXX"
    replaceEveryNumber '8' = "XXXXXXXX"
    replaceEveryNumber c = [c]
    in map replaceEveryNumber givenString
```

Now this will generate a list of `String`s, for example:

```
Prelude> myFunction "abc1abc2abc3"
["a","b","c","X","a","b","c","XX","a","b","c","XXX"]
```

the only thing that we still need to do is concatenate these strings. We can make use of [**`concat :: [[a]] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/GHC-List.html#v:concat), but we can also work with [**`concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/GHC-List.html#v:concatMap):

```
myFunction givenString = let
    replaceEveryNumber '1' = "X"
    replaceEveryNumber '2' = "XX"
    replaceEveryNumber '3' = "XXX"
    replaceEveryNumber '4' = "XXXX"
    replaceEveryNumber '5' = "XXXXX"
    replaceEveryNumber '6' = "XXXXXX"
    replaceEveryNumber '7' = "XXXXXXX"
    replaceEveryNumber '8' = "XXXXXXXX"
    replaceEveryNumber c = [c]
    in concatMap replaceEveryNumber givenString
```

Finally we do not need to write clauses for each digit. We can work with functions like `replicate` and `digitToInt`. I leave that as an exercise.